# Is it possible to create a JSON structure that looks like this

Tags: javascript, json

I am working on sending data from a system to another, and the developer at the remote system sent me an example of a JSON structure I need to have in the body of the REST call.

The structure looks as shown below.

```
{{
    "case": {
        "status": "some status",
        "fields": {
            "field": 
            [
            {
                "name": "some name",
                "selection": "No"
            },
            {
                "name": "some name",
                "approved": true,
                "reason": "some string"
            }
            ]
        }
    }
}}
```

I have no problems creating most of this structure but the part that seemed kind of odd are the double curly brackets ({{...}}) in the beginning and the end.

In my case I would be creating this with JavaScript and add it to the body of the REST message as a JSON structure.

Is it possible to embed the "case" element inside an extra layer of curly brackets? If so, how is that done?

Comment: try http://jsonlint.com/

Comment: No, that's invalid JSON. You can verify JSON structures with a JSON validator or linter such as http://jsonlint.com/

Comment: Would seem either they sent incorrect info or you misinterpreted it

Comment: But why would you create json like this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, that is not [valid JSON syntax](http://www.json.org/).  You can check that yourself e.g. by pasting the code into [JSONLint](http://jsonlint.com/).

Answer (score 2):

You are right, the double curly braces at the beginning and end is not valid JSON syntax.

If you have to send the string exactly like that, you can just generate the JSON string without the outer curly braces and then append `'{'+json_str+'}'` and send it off in the request body.

-- EDIT --

This is a bad practice.  Do this only if the developers of the API that wants data like this are not willing to fix this issue.

Comment: Manually creating json is simply a bad practice and prone to errors

Comment: I do agree it is bad practice.

Comment: Bad practice maybe but thank you for the tip! It may save me some time for a "quick and dirty" solution

Answer (score 0):

U can remove first and last curly and try it again:).

Answer (score 0):

This json sample is not a valid one in neither rfc 4627/7159 or ecma 404.
Try to speak with the other developer and explain him that he made an error.